# How can I retrieve a list of values in an array that has same name but different version?

Tags: python

For example if I have a list:

```
[
    ["nameoffile1","version1","date02/03"],
    ["nameoffile1","version2","date02/04"],
    ["nameoffile2","version2","date05/02"],
    ["nameoffile3","version3","date02/04"]
]
```

if I have to retrieve just the nameoffile1 based on names how can I retrieve those 2 arrays based on names

thanks

Comment: You should try it first, but I would use a list comprehension with an if condition.

Comment: Loop over the list and check `if element[0] == "nameoffile1"`.

Comment: As Kenny mentioned you can use a list comprehension with a condition or use the filter function

Comment: thanks yes I can do that but I will have bunch of filenames so how can I save the names and compared tham after for examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to collect together all the items with the same name.  If you use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create an empty list the first time a name is encountered, it becomes trivial.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for row in lst:
    d[row[0]].append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting TypeError: first argument must be callable or none

Comment: @Cive you didn't name a variable `list` did you?  That's a no-no.

Comment: ohhhhh yeah I thought you mistyped it. I was writing my list instead of list ok now I got it thankss